# how to insert subfigures

Tags: subfloats, subfig

I want to insert subfigures.
I'm using this code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{mnl-author}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{}
\address{}
\abstract{}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}            
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cap}
\caption{SwissRanger by MESA}
\label{fig:cap}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{gmgds}
\caption{D-Imager by Panasonic}
\label{fig:gmgds}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But there are many errors while compiling this that:

> Use of @subfloat doesn't match its definition. \begin{subfigure}[b]{
>
> Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{subfigure}[b]{width=0.3\textwidth}
>
> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \begin{subfigure}[b]{width=0.3\textwidth}
>
> Use of @subfloat doesn't match its definition. \begin{subfigure}{
>
> Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
>
> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
>
> Use of @subfloat doesn't match its definition. \begin{subfigure}{
>
> Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
>
> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}

Please help me out

Comment: I believe you have to `\usepackage{subfigure}` in the preamble for this to work...

Comment: @Raven No, `subcaption` should be enough. But maybe it does not behave correctly with this class…

Comment: Could you please try to use `article` class, add `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and use `example-image.pdf` for all your images? What happens?

Comment: @Raven: No, `subfigure` is deprecated for almost 15 years ... the successor is `subfig` and as TeXnician wrote, `subcaption` would suffice

Comment: @TeXnician The error will be same after using article class

Comment: Definitely remove `\usepackage{subfigure}`. If I remove that line and change to article class (removing `\address`) and the example image your code works fine.